# make date string with specific requirement

Tags: sql, t-sql

i want to make date like `Thu, 31 October 2013` with the help of sql. how ever i surfed lot of articles and finding out this [article](http://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/). In this article i found that one function can make string with specific format.

for reference i include this function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnFormatDate (@Datetime DATETIME, @FormatMask VARCHAR(32))
RETURNS VARCHAR(32)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @StringDate VARCHAR(32)
    SET @StringDate = @FormatMask
    IF (CHARINDEX (‘YYYY’,@StringDate) > 0)
       SET @StringDate = REPLACE(@StringDate, ‘YYYY’,
                         DATENAME(YY, @Datetime))
    IF (CHARINDEX (‘YY’,@StringDate) > 0)
       SET @StringDate = REPLACE(@StringDate, ‘YY’,
                         RIGHT(DATENAME(YY, @Datetime),2))
    IF (CHARINDEX (‘Month’,@StringDate) > 0)
       SET @StringDate = REPLACE(@StringDate, ‘Month’,
                         DATENAME(MM, @Datetime))
    IF (CHARINDEX (‘MON’,@StringDate COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS)>0)
       SET @StringDate = REPLACE(@StringDate, ‘MON’,
                         LEFT(UPPER(DATENAME(MM, @Datetime)),3))
    IF (CHARINDEX (‘Mon’,@StringDate) > 0)
       SET @StringDate = REPLACE(@StringDate, ‘Mon’,
                                     LEFT(DATENAME(MM, @Datetime),3))
    IF (CHARINDEX (‘MM’,@StringDate) > 0)
       SET @StringDate = REPLACE(@StringDate, ‘MM’,
                  RIGHT(’0′+CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEPART(MM, @Datetime)),2))
    IF (CHARINDEX (‘M’,@StringDate) > 0)
       SET @StringDate = REPLACE(@StringDate, ‘M’,
                         CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEPART(MM, @Datetime)))
    IF (CHARINDEX (‘DD’,@StringDate) > 0)
       SET @StringDate = REPLACE(@StringDate, ‘DD’,
                         RIGHT(’0′+DATENAME(DD, @Datetime),2))
    IF (CHARINDEX (‘D’,@StringDate) > 0)
       SET @StringDate = REPLACE(@StringDate, ‘D’,
                                     DATENAME(DD, @Datetime))   
RETURN @StringDate
END
GO

– Microsoft SQL Server date format function test
– MSSQL formatting dates
SELECT dbo.fnFormatDate (getdate(), ‘MM/DD/YYYY’)           – 01/03/2012
SELECT dbo.fnFormatDate (getdate(), ‘DD/MM/YYYY’)           – 03/01/2012
SELECT dbo.fnFormatDate (getdate(), ‘M/DD/YYYY’)            – 1/03/2012
SELECT dbo.fnFormatDate (getdate(), ‘M/D/YYYY’)             – 1/3/2012
SELECT dbo.fnFormatDate (getdate(), ‘M/D/YY’)               – 1/3/12
SELECT dbo.fnFormatDate (getdate(), ‘MM/DD/YY’)             – 01/03/12
SELECT dbo.fnFormatDate (getdate(), ‘MON DD, YYYY’)         – JAN 03, 2012
SELECT dbo.fnFormatDate (getdate(), ‘Mon DD, YYYY’)         – Jan 03, 2012
SELECT dbo.fnFormatDate (getdate(), ‘Month DD, YYYY’)       – January 03, 2012
SELECT dbo.fnFormatDate (getdate(), ‘YYYY/MM/DD’)           – 2012/01/03
SELECT dbo.fnFormatDate (getdate(), ‘YYYYMMDD’)             – 20120103
SELECT dbo.fnFormatDate (getdate(), ‘YYYY-MM-DD’)           – 2012-01-03
– CURRENT_TIMESTAMP returns current system date and time in standard internal format
SELECT dbo.fnFormatDate (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,‘YY.MM.DD’)      – 12.01.03
GO
————
```

i just want to make formate like as i asked. how can i modify this with function or can anybody have another solution for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
DECLARE @dt DATETIME = getdate()
SELECT LEFT(DATENAME(weekday,@dt),3) + ', ' + DATENAME(day,@dt) + ' ' + DATENAME(month,@dt) + ' ' + DATENAME(year,@dt)
```